# Jsoup is giving a different HTML document compared to my browser

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I made sure to use my browser's User Agent, and it still gives a different HTML. I also tried using Jsoup.parse(Url, int) instead of Jsoup.connect(String). The two attempts:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.bulq.com/lots/search/?category=Consumer%20Electronics&condition%5B%5D=Brand%20New")
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.1Safari/605.1.15")
.get();
```

and

```
URL mainUrl = new URL("https://www.bulq.com/lots/search/category=Consumer%20Electronics&condition%5B%5D=Brand%20New");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(mainUrl, 6000);
```

I'm using Safari's "Show Page Source" in the "Elements" tab. I tried to copy some HTML below but the formatting won't work :( so here's a tiny example.

Example: one of the div classes in Jsoup HTML is:

```
div class="row ng-cloak" ui-view
```

while the Safari HTML is:

```
div class="row ng-scope" ui-view
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the difference is? It might be that the "Show page source" isn't displaying everything.

Comment: The documents are similar but definitely not the same, I'll try to Edit with an example

Comment: does the document retrieved by JSoup start with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and the Show page source doesn't show that?

Comment: does elements -> show page source show the original source or the source after generating elements through javascript ("generated source")? those are obviously different.

Comment: No, they both start with !DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @eis How would I go about finding out if it's the original source or not? I'm new to HTML

Comment: @NoClue you can find out if it is the origional source by disabling javascript temporarily for that website ([here](https://www.lifewire.com/disable-javascript-in-safari-4103708) is how to do that).

Comment: if the elements you're trying to find are generated dynamically by javascript, you won't be able to find them unless you execute the javascript on that page (which jsoup would not do)

Comment: @eis I was having trouble using Element.select(String), so I printed out the entire HTML code for the Jsoup document. Then, I control-F the output for things that were in the browser HTML, and found that many things were either named or structured differently

Comment: @NoClue the structure will change somewhat on parsing, but names certainly should not, unless the original has some syntax errors

Comment: Pretty sure I am just fundamentally missing something so I'm going to try to further understand Jsoup and HTML. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try sending `User-Agent` as header with jsoup

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7")
                    .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the page with:

```
URL u = new URL("https://www.google.com/"); //replace https://www.google.com/ with your url
InputStream in = u.openStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

That won't require a library, and maybe that will return the exact page...

Comment: I'm using Jsoup for a web scraper to gather specific links and download specific files from this site. My issue is that I'm trying to use Elements that are in my Safari HTML page that aren't being found by Jsoup.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to know if it would work with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're viewing the live DOM from the Elements tab then some of these classes may be different because of JavaScript, which Jsoup will not run when it fetches the raw HTML from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced the same problem when trying to get content of the `url1` but jsoup return the content of `another url` (may be jsoup being redirected).
Thank to the answer of @Zendy I have found the solution:

- First step: open browser and press F12 to open developer tool, navigate to `Network` tab.
- Navigate browser to the url you need to get content
- Get the user-agent on the request header and set it into your jsoup.
  [image]